# Microsoft graph: Search as external user (guest)

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I am using the Graph API to search SharePoint like its described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files).
For this I created an app with delegated permissions:

> Sites.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.All

Now I can send a POST request to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query" with the following body:

```
{   "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "listItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "{SOME QUERY}"
      },
      "size": 100,
      "fields": [
          "name",
          "author",
          "title",
          "webUrl",
          "size",
          "id",
          "Customer", ... whatever       
      ]
    }   
 ] }
```

This works fine if I do this for *internal users*.
However, if guests are added via Azure B2B collaboration to our SharePoint, they cannot access this endpoint, even though the tokens contain the same scopes (Sites.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.All...)

Graph returns an error message instead a list of files:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
> "message": "\r\n The service is not authorized for provided user credentials",
> "target": "",
> "level": "Error"
> },
> "instrumentation": {
> "traceId": "97d66c34-9643-a0ec-1d08-52d2bc49ab5a"
> }
> }

If I search for "The service is not authorized for provided user credentials" in Google I do not find a single result.
The classical REST endpoint of SharePoint works for them, but I want to upgrade to graph.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi David, first I would suggest using the Graph Explorer for testing if you're not already: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Graph and REST are used for different things, some you cannot do with the other. If it's working for REST and not Graph, there's probably a reason. Can you try a GET request to get all external users and see if that works? If not you may get another error you can pinpoint. I'm still researching this but please let me know what you find.

Comment: Its very likely that I discover exactly a bug that is described here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/1039. I am wondering why there was never an official statement of MS...